# Model Object Issue

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a model object to store json data received from newsAPI. However one of the keys called description matched a reserved keyword in swift. How do I resolve this ? The error message read Error Message: Property 'description' with type 'String?' cannot override a property with type 'String'

```
  class ArticlesData: NSObject {
            var author: String?
            var title: String?
            var description: String?
            var publishedAt: String?
            var urlImage: String?
            var urlWebsite : String?
          
        }

author  :   Andrew Marino
title   :   Vergecast: this week’s Section 230 hearing and the season of weird gadgets
description :   Nilay, Dieter, and Adi discuss the latest Section 230 congressional hearing featuring the CEOs of Big Tech. Ashley Carman stops by to talk about how gadget makers are turning to shopping channels to market their products.
url :   https://www.theverge.com/2020/10/30/21541796/section-230-hearing-gadgets-qvc-razr-2020-review-vergecast-podcast-428
urlToImage  :   https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/sgk9rqbUKhLVhNxKunmuX_Zm6TM=/0x146:2040x1214/fit-in/1200x630/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/19749210/vpavic_200214_3909_samsung_galaxy_Z_flip_0013.jpg
publishedAt :   2020-10-30T14:44:14Z
content :   Photo by Vjeran Pavic / The Verge\n\n This week on The Verge’s flagship podcast, The Vergecast: Sen. Ted Cruz (R-TX) yells at Twitter CEO Jack Dorsey, gadget makers are going to QVC, and it is weird ph… [+3098 chars]
```

Comment: A minor clarification, `description` is not a keyword in Swift. Here it is the name of a property in a superclass so it is already taken.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution: Use a struct, neither a class or even a subclass of `NSObject` is necessary.

```
struct ArticlesData {
```

Otherwise just use a different name.

If you are going to decode the JSON with `Decodable` add `CodingKeys` to map the dictionary key to the struct member with a different name.

And don't declare all properties carelessly as optional. Declare only those as optional which can be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same 'issue' several times and it's quite annoying indeed. You should rename your property to something else.

How are you mapping your JSON into the object? If you use Codable, you can use custom CodingKeys such as:

```
class ArticlesData: NSObject, Codable 
{
    var author: String?
    var title: String?
    var myDescription: String?
    var publishedAt: String?
    var urlImage: String?
    var urlWebsite: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey 
    {
        case author, title, myDescription = "description", publishedAt, urlImage = "urlToImage", urlWebsite = "url"
    }
}
```

EDIT: As [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64711261/2399348) said, you can also use a struct. I actually prefer that solution over renaming the propery to another name than you want.